# Which book has term by term differentiation theorem for multivariable functions series?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm looking for a book with a theorem about term by term differentiation for multivariable functions series.

Comment: For a partial derivative with respect to a particular variable, a single-variable function theorem would seem to apply. Are you asking for a book that makes that observation, or do you mean something different (like the Jacobian matrix of each term)?

Comment: I want to find books on the observation part like you said  "For a partial derivative with respect to a particular variable, a single-variable function theorem would seem to apply."